# QlikView - Use a variable into set analysis expression

Tags: variables, set, analysis, qlikview

I've the variable varCurrentYear

`varCurrentYear = Year(Today())`

And I wrote this set analysis expression

[image: Expression]

The result it’s not correct. By the way If the variable is declared in this way

`varCurrentYear = 2014`

The result is correct.

Why?
Thank's

Answer (score 3):

I'd use

```
Sum({$<Year={'$(varCurrentYear)'}>}Orders)
```

resp without quotes if varCurrentYear is numeric

```
Sum({$<Year={$(varCurrentYear)}>}Orders)
```

See http://tools.qlikblog.at/SetAnalysisWizard/?sa=MCKA

Regards
Stefan

Comment: Hi Stefan,

I have the same problem and I have tried your tips and the set Analysis generator. but it does not worked. May you please have a look on my question which I have just asked.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411577/using-variables-in-set-analysis-expressoin

Answer (score 3):

I know it looks strange, but you have to write:

```
=sum({<Year={"$(=$(varCurrentYear))" } >} Orders)
```

The QlikView parser can evaluate the double-nested variable for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

`=Sum({<Year={$(=varCurrentYear)}>}Orders)`

Comment: How is this different than @stefan's answer?