# Using Variables in Set Analysis Expressoin

Tags: qliksense

I am using the following set analysis and it fails to return the data.

```
=Only({1<Month={"$(vMonthNr)"}>} Minutes)
```

Where: vMonthNr = Month('$(vFromDate)')

I have tried to use a variable which has fixed value. in this case, It works perfectly. please see the expression bellow.

```
=Only({1<Month={"$(vMonth)"}>} Minutes)
```

where vMonth = 4

The variable "vFromDate" takes its value from a calendar extension. and the field Minutes comes from this Data.

```
[Table1]:
LOAD * inline ["Month", "Minutes"
        1, 12000,
         2, 12600,
         3, 12600,
         4, 12600,
         5, 12000,
         6, 13200,
         7, 12600,
         8, 13800,
         9, 13200,
         10, 12000,
         11, 13200,
         12, 12600,];
```

When the variable has a plain value it works but when the variable has an expression it does not works.

Kindly note: I have tried to applied the answers in this Question ( [QlikView - Use a variable into set analysis expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935829/qlikview-use-a-variable-into-set-analysis-expression) ) but unfortunately it does not worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer and it has solved my issue. Here it is:

vMonthNr = Num(Month('$(vFromDate)'))

Comment: nice! can you mark this as the correct answer as well? Thanks

Comment: Actually, Stackoverflow prevents to choose your own answer as the correct one before 2 days. I would try again after 2 days :D

Thanks Chris.